# Using AWS EC2 to maintain persistant connection to Twitter API? Even when closing terminal window?

Tags: ubuntu, twitter, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am attempting to pull data from the Twitter Streaming API, specifically [POST statuses/filter](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/reference/post/statuses/filter).

The challenge that I'm faced with is that I need a persistent connection to the data, meaning my computer cannot randomly restart or lose the internet connection.  I thought this would be a perfect opportunity to an AWS EC2 Ubuntu instance, and that way, I can rely on Amazon's connection for consistent data collection.

So that's what I did.  I created a basic tier EC2 Ubuntu instance, connected to it, and started my query that I created using `cURL` and the Twitter OAuth Signing Result that was generated by the Twitter Dev signature generator.  This allowed me to collect the data just as I always have and wanted to, however, if I closed terminal window, my query ended.

I know there are other ways to collect Twitter data, but I would like to work with the Twitter Dev signature generator to avoid all of the other complications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to keep the process running in the background even after you closed the ssh session using `screen` and `nohup`.

- `nohup` allows to run command/process or shell script that can continue running in the background after you log out from a shell:

  ```
  nohup /path/to/command &
  ```
- `screen` is helpful in keeping a session alive even after disconnecting from it, even better screen allows to reconnect to the disconnected session, you might have to install screen as it does not get installed by default.

  - To start a screen session:

    ```
    screen -S sessionname
    ```
  - Detaching from screen:

    ```
    "Ctrl-a" "d"
    ```
  - Reattach to a screen:

    ```
     screen -r
    ```

  More about screen [here](https://www.linode.com/docs/networking/ssh/using-gnu-screen-to-manage-persistent-terminal-sessions)